# compare same data into table and delete different data by : Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
Suppose I have  two
DataTable A 
AS column 
ID :1 3 
Name : One Three

DataTable B 
AS column 
ID :   1 3 4 5 6
Name : One Three Four Five six
```

my question is

Compare two tables and find only mismatching data Linq

how can we write a linq to Delete record /return a table with only Different record in   compare both tables 
any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that A and B have rows of the same type:

```
A.Union(B).Except(A.Intersect(B))
```

Comment: thank you i already try above suggestion
but thing is what we do if we have to different column in row ?

Comment: That depends what you expect your result set to look like.